# Match everything after and before something regex Java

Tags: java, regex

Here is my code:

```
    String stringToSearch = "https://example.com/excludethis123456/moretext";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=.com\\/excludethis).*\\/"); //search for this pattern 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch); //match pattern in StringToSearch

    String store= "";


    // print match and store match in String Store
    if (m.find())
    {
        String theGroup = m.group(0);
        System.out.format("'%s'\n", theGroup); 
        store = theGroup;
    }

    //repeat the process
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.*)[^\\/]");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(store);

    if (m1.find())
    {
        String theGroup = m1.group(0);
        System.out.format("'%s'\n", theGroup);
    }
```

I want to to match everything that is after `excludethis` and before a `/` that comes after.

With `"(?<=.com\\/excludethis).*\\/"` regex I will match `123456/` and store that in `String store`. After that with `"(.*)[^\\/]"` I will exclude `/` and get `123456`.

Can I do this in one line, i.e combine these two regex? I can't figure out how to combine them.

Comment: How about using `.com/excludethis(\d+)/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have used a positive look behind, you can use a positive look ahead and change your regex to this,

```
(?<=.com/excludethis).*(?=/)
```

Also, in Java you don't need to escape `/`

Your modified code,

```
String stringToSearch = "https://example.com/excludethis123456/moretext";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=.com/excludethis).*(?=/)"); // search for this pattern
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch); // match pattern in StringToSearch

String store = "";

// print match and store match in String Store
if (m.find()) {
    String theGroup = m.group(0);
    System.out.format("'%s'\n", theGroup);
    store = theGroup;
}
System.out.println("Store: " + store);
```

Prints,

```
'123456'
Store: 123456
```

Like you wanted to capture the value.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for you :)

```java
String stringToSearch = "https://example.com/excludethis123456/moretext";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("excludethis([\\d\\D]+?)/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToSearch);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String result = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `regex`, you could just try with [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))*

```
String stringToSearch = "https://example.com/excludethis123456/moretext";
String exclusion = "excludethis";
System.out.println(stringToSearch.substring(stringToSearch.indexOf(exclusion)).substring(exclusion.length(), stringToSearch.substring(stringToSearch.indexOf(exclusion)).indexOf("/")));
```

**Output:**

> 123456

* <sub>Definitely don't actually use this</sub>